# In Scala [2.11.6] how would one create a lazy stream of objects from an ordered set of Longs

Tags: scala

In a nutshell what I wish to do is take a set of `Longs`, arbitrarily ordered as in (7,3,9,14,123,2) and have available a series of `Objects`:

```
Set(SomeObject(7),SomeObject(3),SomeObject(9),SomeObject(14),SomeObject(123),SomeObject(2))
```

However I do not want the `SomeObject` objects initialized until I actually ask for them. I wish to be able to ask for them in arbitrary order as well: As in give me the 3rd `SomeObject` (by index) or give me the `SomeObject` that maps to the Long value of 7. All that without triggering initializations down the stack.

I understand a lazy stream however I'm not quite sure how to connect the dots between the first Set of Longs (map will do that instantly of course as in `map { x => SomeObject(x)}`) and yet end up with a `Lazy Stream` (in the same initial arbitrary order please!)

One of the additional rules is this needs to be `Set` based so I never have the same `Long` (and it's matching `SomeObject`) appear twice.

An additional need is to to handle multiple `Sets` of `Longs` initially being mashed together, while maintaining the (fifo) order and uniqueness but I believe that is all built into a subclass of Set to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

`Set` doesn't provide a indexed access so you can't get "*3rd SomeObject*". Also `Set` cant provide you any operations without evaluating values that it contains because this values need to be ordered (in case of Tree-based implementation) or hashed (in case of HashSets), and you cant sort or hash value that you do not know.

If creation of `SomeObject` is resource consuming maybe it is better to create a "`SomeObjectHolder`" class that would create `SomeObject` on demand and provide hashing operations that will not require creation of `SomeObject`.

Than you will have

```
Set(SomeObjectHolder(7),SomeObjectHolder(3),SomeObjectHolder(9),...
```

And each `SomeObjectHolder` will create corresponding `SomeObject` for you when you need.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your requirements can be satisfied by lazy `view` of some indexed sequence:

```
case class SomeObject(v:Long) {
  println(s"$v created")
}

val source = Vector(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
val col = source.view.map(SomeObject.apply)
```

In this case, when you access individual elements by index `col(2)` only requested elements are evaluated. However when you request `slice`, all elements from 0 to endpoint are evaluated.

```
col.slice(1, 2).toList
```

Prints:

```
0 created
1 created
```

This approach has several drawbacks:

- when you request element several times, it get's evaluated each time
- when you request `slice`, all elements from the beginning are evaluated
- you can't request mapping for arbitrary key (only for index)

---

To satisfy all you requirements custom class should be created:

```
class CachedIndexedSeq[K, V](source: IndexedSeq[K], func: K => V) extends IndexedSeq[V] {
  private val cache = mutable.Map[K, V]()

  def getMapping(key: K): V = cache.getOrElseUpdate(key, func(key))

  override def length: Int = source.length

  override def apply(idx: Int): V = getMapping(source(idx))
}
```

This class takes source indexed sequence as the argument along with mapping function. It lazily evaluates elements and also provides `getMapping` method to lazily map arbitrary key.

```
val source = Vector(0L, 1L, 2L)
val col2 = new CachedIndexedSeq[Long, SomeObject](source, SomeObject.apply)

col2.slice(1, 3).toList
col2(1)
col2(1)
col2.getMapping(1L)
```

Prints:

```
1 created
2 created
```

The only remaining requirement is the ability to avoid duplicates. `Set` doesn't combine well with requesting elements by index. So I suggest to put all your initial Longs into any indexed seq (such as `Vector`) and then call `distinct` on them, before wrapping in `CachedIndexedSeq`.

Comment: I like the view concept - not seen the map directly to an apply function before so thank you for that it will come in handy! I'm trying to do this a functionally as possible as I need this for potentially over a hundred TYPES of objects so I would prefer to write everything once. Some (all?) of what your describing might be workable into a trait however...